# Change animation trigger on mouseover

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have a bunch of thumbnails and I would like an overlay slide to appear from the bottom of the thumbnail when the user hovers over the thumbnail and have the overlay retract when the user isn't hovering over the thumbnail.

```js
animations: [
  trigger('overlaySlide', [
    state('in', style({})),
    transition(':enter', [
      style({
        transform: 'translateX(-100%)'
      }),
      animate('0.5s ease')
    ]),
    transition(':leave', [
      style({
        transform: 'translateX(-100%)'
      }),
      animate('0.5s ease')
    ])
  ])
]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="gallery" class="text-center">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let picture of gameImages">
    <img src="/assets/images/maple.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="overlay-text" [@overlaySlide]> Hello World</div>
    </div>
  </ng-container>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `:enter` and `:enter` keywords, you need to remove the element from the DOM. Try something like this:

`<div @overlaySlide *ngIf="show" (mouseenter)="show = true" (mouseleave)="show = false"> Hello World</div>`

Comment: it's difficult mouseenter if !show :). the events must be put in the img tag